# How to use Ext.net control in MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ext.net

i want to use Ext.net control in aspnet mvc 3 but i can not do that. Can you help me?

```
<h2>List</h2>
<div>
        <% Ext.Net.TabPanel tb = new TabPanel() { ID="tb1", Height = 300 };
           tb.Items.Add(new Ext.Net.Panel() { ID = "1", Title = "Test" });


        %>
    </div>
```

But no result return to me if i look page source result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/WebResource.axd?d=yZr1qXAiAzbIyuMwWFg4QLahCw7ja-r5MvwrWaYGNYBiSLompC1t3Dre6yVT_nX3dE_5QRW8Pq_M_mf3ckpaRofaHZG9JTWR4XNA3Qlk1l0lrRtAk7_XdSqezLOHVVzNAnFsM_Xvd-_Jkz3oAxnZR52Pj2Gx6OQ6XgRMpjV7wg41&t=634661604900000000" />
<title>

    List

</title>
     <style type="text/css">
      html
      {
         background-color:Gray;
      }

      .column
      {
         float:left;
         width:75%;
         border:solid 1px black;
         margin-right:10px;
         padding:5px;
         background-color:white;
         min-height:750px;
      }

   </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/WebResource.axd?d=EEB3ci-aaYX0YFB1eKO9bNJxz21l7U6Xgp6gafhX-ELA3dqrXi0vJChPyMcsY02FqNHlDFzFUXhC1Wr20e23KQDHybExiJcMtk25sY6H14MJWhlFGE-pP5O0yfnfTY5rqctCxUyaF0PEA-FTaqBmsMnVHTwakoGf9vavE-17ugQ1&t=634661604900000000"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/WebResource.axd?d=MC7em5dhNLnBAdrW93hZYkG4dXWQcASL6iXw2IQb1NzxHMGA11tPZfow93hy4T_4dZqotlxW-YF95RJptzY352oINWGWb6cJr4JvBvRDC0amtlBU65lPTxvQeag4qmgoBXQ3Y-KW6mtrxsiGMKkIRQ2&t=634661604900000000"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/WebResource.axd?d=hG2uE2_g7tabtfNStz4lSLSwuXYXbXisubF7Fk7ezPJp9TZl2fyBJu3H-wYG-DS9JithBK3TA4ThRCkhX53y2HlV02jYOaX-dL8EVSpL2hvpa6PYag6EVudAnf_JzCoPcMqKXc2dJ0PFK5qP7XXZeQ2&t=634661604900000000"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        Ext.net.ResourceMgr.init({id:"ctl00$ResourceManager1",BLANK_IMAGE_URL:"/WebResource.axd?d=SanxrxztuPyOAwG7dcFi5HvB6yOoIwnKJN3sevUiXssgue_dNhgx0KWC2p7tE4ygV4N6_n3aqstZCgfhUs4nL5nCZggPLeFdFhYYgXln5EK0OaMOfRO77y22sclo4saMp9irYOG5hNb8NvsMMkgeqm9TCwonBfPgYchN-BVRq4c1&t=634661604900000000",theme:"blue"});Ext.onReady(function(){Ext.QuickTips.init();});
    //]]>
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="column">
       <h1>Job Schedule </h1>


<h2>List</h2>
<div>

    </div>



    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you have posted is WebForm syntax.

If you are using ASP.NET MVC Razor and the latest Ext.NET v2.x release, you can render all/any of the Ext.NET Components using Razor syntax.

The following sample demonstrates rendering a very simple TabPanel.

**Example**

```
@{
    Layout = "";    
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Ext.NET Examples</title>
</head>
<body>    
    @Html.X().ResourceManager()

    @(Html.X().TabPanel()
        .Height(300)
        .Items(items => {
            items.Add(Html.X().Panel().Title("Test"));
        }));
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you give me some samples Ext.Net in mvc 3  how to do that?

Comment: Hey @programmerist, did you find any samples??? I also wanna use ext.net controls with asp.net mvc razor engine. But I am stuck due to lack of samples. It would be great if you provide me with samples if you have any.

Answer (score 1):

`Page.Controls` is present only in web forms. I suspect that your control is for web forms, therefore it won't work with MVC.